# ''No database selected'' error in Render

Tags: mysql, sequelize

I created a project on Node js(Express js) with sequelize ORM and earlier, I used sequelize-cli to create and migrate database and tables respectively.

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "library-management",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "install-and-migrate": "npm install && sequelize-cli db:create && sequelize-cli db:migrate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mysql2": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

and this is my config.js file after changing it from config.json:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const config = {
  dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT || "mysql",
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
  port: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME || "root",
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
};

// console.log(config);

module.exports = {
  url: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_URL,
  development: { ...config, database: process.env.DB_DEVELOPMENT_NAME },
  test: { ...config, database: process.env.DB_TEST_NAME },
  production: { ...config, database: process.env.DB_PROD_NAME },
};
```

and
.sequelizerc:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
//   'seeders-path': path.resolve('seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('migrations')
};
```

and my app.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes")
const adminRoutes = require("./routes/adminRoutes")
const bookRoutes = require("./routes/bookRoutes")
const authorRoutes = require("./routes/authorRoutes")

app.use(express.json())

app.use('/users',userRoutes)
app.use('/book',bookRoutes)
app.use('/author',authorRoutes)
app.use('/admin',adminRoutes)

app.listen(3000);
```

When I started the deployment operation, it showed me that:

```
Nov 23 10:46:38 AM  Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.17.0, CLI: 6.6.2, ORM: 6.35.1]
Nov 23 10:46:38 AM  
Nov 23 10:46:38 AM  Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Nov 23 10:46:38 AM  Using environment "development".
Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  Database bzkjl4pacusbj3w7ymkv created.
Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  
Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.17.0, CLI: 6.6.2, ORM: 6.35.1]
Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  
Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  Using environment "development".
Nov 23 10:46:44 AM  No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.
```

But when I started inserting the endpoints using PostMan, it's telling me that:

```
    Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
  original: Error: No database selected
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Packet.asError (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Query.execute (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Connection.handlePacket (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    code: 'ER_NO_DB_ERROR',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    errno: 1046,
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    sqlState: '3D000',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    sqlMessage: 'No database selected',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    sql: 'SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `role`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `age`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User`;',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    parameters: undefined
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
  },
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
  sql: 'SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `role`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `age`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User`;',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
  parameters: {}
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
}
```

I have shared my concerns in their community room but I still cannot figure out whether is this happening from my side or from theirs.

because its still working in the localhost.

I am using cleaver-cloud to create a mysql add-on so that I can create a live database.